# Resolving a promise with Promise.all followed by synchronous failure

Tags: javascript

I am trying to resolve a promise using Promise.all and, once I got all data, continue to manipulate the data synchronously. Asynchronous action is successful but synchronous code doesn't complete, strangely. What could I be doing wrong? Any help appreciated. My code is below...

```
Promise.all(urls.map(url => fetch(url, options).then(res => res.json())))
                .then(([aptByMonth, availability, daysOff, timesOff]) => {
                console.log(aptByMonth, availability, daysOff, timesOff) // this data is fetched correctly
                dispatch(getTrainerAppointmentsByMonthSuccess(aptByMonth, dateString))
                dispatch(getTrainerAvailabilitySuccess(availability))
                dispatch(fetchTrainerDaysOffSuccess(daysOff))
                dispatch(fetchTrainerTimesOffSuccess(timesOff));
                dispatch(fetchDatabaseSuccess({ aptByMonth, availability, daysOff, timesOff }));
                
            })
            .catch(err => dispatch(fetchDatabaseError(err)))
    }
}

export const fetchDatabaseRequest = () => {
    return {
        type: 'FETCH_DATABASE_REQUEST'
    }
}

export const fetchDatabaseSuccess = () => {
    return {
        type: 'FETCH_DATABASE_SUCCESS'
    }
}

export const getTrainerAppointmentsByMonthSuccess = (data, date) => {
    return {
        type: 'GET_TRAINER_APPOINTMENTS_BY_MONTH_SUCCESS',
        payload: data,
        date: date
    }
};

export const getTrainerAvailabilitySuccess = (data) => {
    console.log('RAW DATA: ', data) // data is here
    const rawAvailability = data
    
    let mondayAvailability = [];

    for (let item of rawAvailability) {
        if (item.week_day === 'Monday') {
            mondayAvailability.push(item);
        }
    }

    (...)

    console.log('test', wednesdayAvailability) // this doesn't run
}
```

Comment: Your `then` calback is not returning anything (which would become the resolved value)

Comment: @trincot it is though. data is being successfully retrieved

Comment: Sure, it is, I am just saying your `Promise.all` is not effective. It serves no purpose.

Comment: Are those dispatches synchronous? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: @Konowy yes, those dispatches are synchronous. not getting any errors either.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you are using some redux and dispatch takes string as a parameter.